# Replace only the First occurrence of a string in a file using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, solaris

I have the following sed command :

```
sed 's'~"-log -asofdate $newAsOfDate "'~'"-log1"'~1'  /export/home/ownclp/temp/runjava.sh.bk > $runjavaPath
```

but instead of replacing just the first occurrence it is replacing all occurrence.
Note : `~` is my delimiter.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you mean it is replacing the value more than once on a given line or on more than one line in the file? Also the quoting of that command is horrible (and unnecessarily complicated).

Comment: it replaces the value multiple times on a line.
Sorry about the quoting. i'm new to Unix, still not very comfortable with the syntax

Comment: What version of sed is this?

Comment: To expand on Etan Reisner's comment . . . you can make your command *much* easier to read by simplifying the quoting, replacing `'s'~"-log -asofdate $newAsOfDate "'~'"-log1"'~1'` with `"s~-log -asofdate $newAsOfDate ~-log1~1"`. Additionally, a delimiter like `|` or `#` might be easier to read in your case, because `-` is so similar to `~` that the `~-` parts are hard to decipher at a glance. So: `"s#-log -asofdate $newAsOfDate #-log1#1"`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ruakh. Its made my script so much easier to read

Comment: I'm using solaris sed. Not sure about the version number.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you want to replace only the first instance of the pattern on the first line where it appears you want something like this:

```
sed "0,/-log -asofdate $newAsOfDate /s~-log -asofdate $newAsOfDate ~-log1~"  /export/home/ownclp/temp/runjava.sh.bk > "$runjavaPath"
```

As `$newAsOfDate` appears to have a `/` in it you would need to use an alternate address regex marker like this instead:

```
sed "0,\~-log -asofdate $newAsOfDate ~s~-log -asofdate $newAsOfDate ~-log1~"  /export/home/ownclp/temp/runjava.sh.bk > "$runjavaPath"
```

Comment: Using your solution gave me an Unrecognized command: 0,/-log -asofdate 01/08/2015 /s~-log -asofdate 01/08/2015 ~-log1~ error.

Comment: That's because of the slashes in the pattern. Updating.

Comment: using the updated version, there is no change at all in the file. is there an alternate way of doing this thats easier, maybe using awk ?

Comment: The output file isn't different then the input file with this command? What version of `sed` is this? If you remove the `0,\~....~` bit I added and just use the quote-simplified version here does it replace the parts you want (and extra parts)?

Comment: I'm using the solaris sed. 
If i skip the 0,\~ part and use the simplified version all the matched strings are replaced

Comment: What sed exactly? Solaris has a history of shipping known-broken versions of various tools as well as known-sane versions of the tools in alternate directories. If you don't need to use the default version using the alternate version might serve you well. That said I can't see why the Solaris sed would default to modifying multiple matches on a single line since that's against spec as far as I know (and why the `g` flag exists).

Comment: yeah its pretty weird. Removing or keeping the g flag seems to make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '\~-log -asofdate '"$newAsOfDate"' ~{s//-log1/;:a;n;ba}' oldFile >newFile
```

This substitutes the required string for the first match and then reads and prints the remainder of the file.

This alternative may work for you:

```
sed -e '\~-log -asofdate '"$newAsOfDate"' ~!b' -e 's//-log1/' -e ':a' -e 'n' -e 'ba' oldFile >newFile
```

The first command is a match on any address that contains the required string. The alternate delimiter `~` is used incase the shell variable `"$newAsOfDate"` contains the default `/` delimiter. If a match is not made (hence `!b`) the line is printed as normal, the command `b` means break from the sequence of commands following and as there is no place holder following the `b` print the current command begins again at the first command. The second `-e` statement means following a match, substitute the matched part of the previous address and replace it with `-log1`. The next three statements set up the mechanism of a loop. The first is a namespace or loop place holder `:a`, the second command `n` means print the current line and then replace the pattern space with the next line, and lastly the `ba` command means return to the loop place holder `:a`. The `n` command also quits any outstanding commands once the last line has been printed.

Comment: I'm using Solaris sed, so this would definitely not work

Comment: @ArchitSharma I'm not familiar with Solaris (and to what version of sed it uses) but normally I have found by splitting the above command into separate commands and using the `-e` option you may achieve your goal. See edit.

Comment: could you explain your answer? then i can try converting it into solaris format